# Having trouble reading and printing out a .csv file

Tags: java, csv, io, filereader, numberformatexception

```
package animalfilereader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class AnimalFileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Creates new Object of BufferedReader for the file animals.csv

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "\\Users\\Greg\\Desktop\\hobbies and personal\\School\\Classwork\\Java 2\\Week 3\\Individual\\AnimalFileReader\\src\\animalfilereader\\animals.csv"));

        // reads file in sections

       String line = null;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        int index = 0;
        List<Animal> aniList = new ArrayList<>();
    // While lines are not null this runs if compiler detects no data program ends outputs results
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Animal ani = new Animal();
            scanner = new Scanner(line);
        // searches for Delimiter comma to separate forms of data
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            //assigns values to different indexes
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String data = scanner.next();
                if (index == 0)
                    ani.setId(Integer.parseInt(data));
                else if (index == 1)
                    ani.setName(data);
                else if (index == 2)
                    ani.setType(data);
                else if (index == 3)
                    ani.setAge(data);
                else
                    System.out.println("invalid data " + data);
                index++;
            }
            index = 0;
            aniList.add(ani);
        }
        //Iterator use

     System.out.print("Animal file: ");
      Iterator itr = aniList.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
         Object element = itr.next();
         System.out.print(element + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

        //close reader
        reader.close();
        //non iterator
        System.out.println(aniList);

    }

}
```

Followed by the classes and .csv file

```
package animalfilereader;
/**
 * @author Greg
 */
public class Animal {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String age;

    //getters and setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    // appending and reading 
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nID = "+getId()+" Name: "+getName()+" Type = "+getType()+" Age = "+getAge();
    }
}
```

animals.csv

```
1,Timone,Meerkat,5 years old 
2,Pumba,Warthog,7 years old 
3,Simba,Lion,3 years old 
4,Rafiki,Monkey,50 years old
```

I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "data"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at animalfilereader.AnimalFileReader.main(AnimalFileReader.java:51)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Not sure what is going on. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try printing out the `line` before you put it into the parser, to make sure it's reading the correct data. One note: obviously you are on a Mac, so no reason to use `\\​` as the file separator. On the Mac it's `/`.

Comment: Well, it says >>For input string: "data"<< Somehow the string "data" is passed to parseInt instead of the data variable. Is not there quotation marks in your ide around this variable? (or does the csv has a header also maybe?)

Comment: I am on pc the \\ is for the \ character inside quotes.  I thought because data is a variable and not a string per say  like parseInt("12345"); but rather holds data that was assigned earlier in the program.

Comment: I figured it out I just turned the id into a string works like a champ now ... such a headache